# Multiprocessing not parallelizing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a function that can be run in parallel, however, as I try running it, it appears that the function is being called serially.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
def function_to_be_parallelized(x,y,z):
    #compute_array takes 1-5 minutes computation to depending on x,y,z
    computed_array=compute_array(x,y,z)
    print ("running with parameters"+str(x*y*z))
    return computed_array

def run(xs,ys,zs):

    pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)
    all_outputs = [pool.apply(function_to_be_parallelized, args=(x,y,z)) for x in xs for y in ys for z in zs]
```

What I find is that the print statements are printed one at a time, and each is only printed once the previous process is finished, I'm running this on a machine with 4 cores.

Is this because the processes in the inner function each occupy more than 2 cores (so that it cannot be parallelized)? Or is there another reason?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: `for x in xs for y in ys for z in zs` almost certainly isn't what you want

Comment: Your function runs in a very quickly.  Just what sort of interleaving did you expect?  Even when I fix just enough errors in your posted code (I'm not sure what it's supposed to demonstrate) to let it run, it does just what I'd expect -- which I believe is what you're describing.

Comment: @Prune, it's impossible for me to write the whole code here so that you can reproduce the problem, it has a lot of dependencies in my own code base. The function is obviously more than I have written here, so it's not fast enough to not get interleaving. I'm trying to understand what can be achieved with mp.pool()

Comment: It's not impossible. The code need only illustrate the fundamental issue you're facing, not be something tied to you or actual issue

Comment: Ok thanks, I've updated the function, let me know if it's clearer now.

Comment: Also, what's wrong with the list comprehension? that part works fine (without the parallelization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pool.apply` [waits for the result to be ready](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply), so you're not submitting a new job until the previous job finishes. You'd have to use something like `apply_async` or `map`, but even then, there's no guarantee you'll see interleaved or out-of-order execution, and the benefits of parallelization will probably be swamped by overhead for a function like this.

Comment: Thanks, the inner function takes actually quite long (many dependencies), so the problem here is with "apply"? then what's the point of having pool.apply if it always executes them serially?

Answer (score -2):

<strike>This looks okay to me. It is likely an issue with waiting for the print buffer to fill.</strike> Look into apply_async: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async

Also,
The print command is being called, python will not send your `print` to stdout unless there is enough stuff in there. Try adding a `sys.stdout.flush()` into your `function_to_be_parallellized` to force printing ASAP.

Comment: It absolutely doesn't look ok to me. The list comprehension looks very wrong and there's no desired output given to say otherwise

Comment: Yep, you got me. I always use apply_async, which I believe should work in this case, and is what I was imagining, while apply is blocking. Issues with the list comprehension aside, apply_async should be used here.